# Why can't a constant property of a struct be used in a following example

Tags: swift

I have a following code from the Swift Design Patterns book:

```swift
protocol Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    static var idKey: WritableKeyPath<Self, ID> { get }
}

struct Book: Identifiable {
    static let idKey = \Book.isbn
    var isbn: String
    var title: String
}
```

It works fine. However, if I change the `Book` declaration using `let` instead of `var` for the `isbn` property, I receive an error: `Type 'Book' does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'`. So the whole erroneous code looks like:

```swift
protocol Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    static var idKey: WritableKeyPath<Self, ID> { get }
}

struct Book: Identifiable {    // error: Type 'Book' does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'
    static let idKey = \Book.isbn
    let isbn: String
    var title: String
}
```

I'm curious why does this happen. I try to run the code inside Xcode Playground file.

Comment: Adding default value doesn't help. However, making it `var` does work. I stated this fact in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a WritableKeyPath - you need to write to it.
It must be a variable in order to be writable.

***In your Book struct you are instantiating a KeyPath with a literal.***
This fails when the KeyPath is not a ***WritableKeyPath***

From the docs:
"A key path that supports reading from and writing to the resulting value."

Meaning that the underlying value must be a variable.

The Following does compile:

```
import UIKit


//https://iswift.org/playground?ZEJ6cL&v=4

protocol Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    static var idKey: WritableKeyPath<Self, ID> { get }
}

struct Book: Identifiable {
    static let idKey = \Book.title
    let isbn: String
    var title: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed it does compile :). I spotted that if I use regular `KeyPath` instead of writable one, I get an error when I use `var` for the property that keyPath targets. So KeyPath classes just leverage the writability feature on the property declarations.

Comment: WritableKeyPath is a subclass of Keypath with the extra ability of writing to - so the subject must be mutable. Btw, most of the time you won’t observe a property that cannot change. :)